# How do I find the derivative $f(x) = \int_{x^{13/14}}^{15\pi} \sqrt{q} \cot(q)dq$

Tags: integration

How do I find the derivative $f(x) = \int_{x^{13/14}}^{15\pi} \sqrt{q} \cot(q)dq$

The problem I am running into is that $15\pi$ is not in the continuous range of the function $\sqrt{x}\cot(x)$ hence the fundamental theorem of calculus can not be applied. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integrand has a non-integrable singularity at multiples of $\pi$, so the integral doesn't converge, and $f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: This happens to be the correct answer; despite asking to solve the problem, they wanted us to recognize it is not solvable with FTC part 1.